# How can I use tilde in the powershell prompt?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

So I get that:

```
function global:prompt {
    # Commands go here
}
```

Sets the prompt in powershell. I can use `Get-Location` to get the current working directory. And I can `cd ~` and be in my home dir.

But can I make the prompt use the tilde? E.g., if I'm in `/home/mike` it should just show `~`.

I've tried testing with:

```
$pwd -contains $home
```

But the results aren't correct.

**How can I use ~ in the prompt in powershell?**

Comment: This looks like an approach to do as you want https://github.com/gummesson/kapow/blob/master/themes/bashlet.ps1 Make the prompt function get the cwd and if cwd = home dir, then replace with "~"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can replace `$HOME` with `~` using normal string replacement. Ex.

Get the current prompt-function:

```
Get-Content Function:\prompt

    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
    # .Link
    # http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
    # .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
```

Then replace `$home` with `~` when the current path is `$home` or `$home\*`.

Using switch (readable):

```
function global:prompt {

    $path = switch -Wildcard ($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path) {
        "$HOME" { "~" }
        "$HOME\*" { $executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path.Replace($HOME, "~") }
        default { $executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path }
    }

    "PS $path$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
}
```

Using regex (recommended):

```
function global:prompt {

    $regex = [regex]::Escape($HOME) + "(\\.*)*$"

    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path -replace $regex, '~$1')$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";

}
```

Using `Split-Path` (ugly):

```
function global:prompt {

    $path = $executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path
    $p = $path

    while ($p -ne "") {
        if($p -eq $HOME) { $path = $path.Replace($HOME,"~"); break}
        $p = Split-Path $p
    }

    "PS $path$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";

}
```

Demo:

```
PS C:\> cd ~

PS ~> cd .\Desktop

PS ~\Desktop>
```

Comment: What if my home is `C:\SomeDir` and my current location is `C:\SomeDirSomethingElse`?

Comment: What @PetSerAl said. I was hoping for a function that treats directories as directories rather than strings, hence handling these kinds of issues. Have an upvote for answering anyway though!

Comment: @FrodeF. thanks but that still seems like a string replace, eg, casing, wouldn't handle certain situation - is there a function to determine whether a dir contains and another dir?

Comment: Nothing built-in as far as I know. The path itself, both in `$pwd.Path` and `$home` are strings, so you would need to use string replacement to modify it to use tilde anyways. Both solutions should work fine and are not case-sensitive. You could run `Split-Path` multiple times to loop through parents and match those values, but you still need string-replacement to edit the value so the loop is just a waste of time when ex. regex is much less code). See third solution in updated answer for `Split-Path`-approach

Comment: There's a directory object in Powershell, and filesystem objects are better handled as filesystem objects rather than strings (so slashes etc don't become an issue). I was hoping for a function that took a directory, and a current user, and returned a tilde's version if such a thing exists.