# Getting Vim to work with Go under Windows

Tags: windows, vim, go

How do I configure Vim running under Windows to be able to edit Golang code? I have spent 3 hours trawling through incomplete, self referential guides on this subject and I grow weary with the resultant frustration.

Ok more details. I have Vim installed. The folder structure is:

`Program Files (x86) -> Vim 
                           vim80
                               autoload
                               colors
                               ...
                           vimfiles`

An example of my confusion is the fact that the installation guide to vim-plug, in the sections about Powershell, simply says to issue the line:

```
md ~\vimfiles\autoload
```

What are these folders relative to?
I have an existing `autoload` folder but it is under the `vim80` folder, hence my confusion. The aforementioned folder structure  is the default one created by the Vim installer.

Comment: This isn't even a question...

Comment: Dave - what part of "All I am after is a step by step guide..." do you not understand?

Comment: Well, technically Dave was right, it was a statement not a question. What have you tried and how didn't it work? Is `vim-go` not working, or are you missing some of the go tooling? There's not much use is people listing things that you've already done, but last time I installed it I used `vim-plug`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`~` in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186373/how-can-i-use-tilde-in-the-powershell-prompt) refers to `$HOME` wnich by default [means `%USERPROFILE%`](https://superuser.com/a/332873/141)

So `~\vimfiles\autoload` are user settings used by `vim80/autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

The ~ characters is your Userprofile as said by VonC.

You can therefore create the vimfiles folder under your user directories:
    `C:\Users\username\vimfiles`

These will be loaded after the core files under the vim installation location `Program files(x86)\Vim\vim80` but both folders same a similar purpose.
Using the user directory is recommended if multiple users are using the same vim installation while having different plugins and a different vimrc.

Note that this also works with the vimrc file:
    You can place your `_vimrc` or `.vimrc`in `C:\Users\username\` and it will be loaded by vim.